# Navigation from login to another page is not happening in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-redux

Here I have created a login form, and in the reducer I already store the registered user's email and password. If any one gives proper login credentials, they will go to the logout component; otherwise, they will throw an alert saying "try again." , I have created that using Redux, so in the app components, I have written logic that if some one gives proper email and password, they will navigate to the logout components; otherwise, they stay in the form components. But the problem is that if I give proper credentials, it will not navigate to the logout components. Still,still blank page is showing, but there is no error we are getting. So what is the problem and How to navigate and show the data of users IDs and provide proper credentials, app components code is given below

```
import "./App.css";
import Form from "./Components/Form";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Logout from "./Components/Logout";

function App() {
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);
  if (users.email && users.password) {
    return (
      <>
        <Logout />
      </>
    );
  } else
    return (
      <>
        <Form />
      </>
    );
}

export default App;

//Form or Login components code is given below




 import { useState } from "react";
    import "./Form.module.scss";
    import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
    export default function Form() {
      const [name, setName] = useState("");
      const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
      const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);
      const register = () => {
        const payload = users.find(
          (user) => user.email === email && user.password === password
        );
        if (payload) {
          dispatch({
            type: "REGISTER",
            payload: {
              id: new Date().getTime(),
              email,
              password,
            },
          });
        } else {
          alert("try again");
        }
      };
      const handleSubmit =(e) =>{
        e.preventDefault()
      }
      return (
        <>
          <form className="border login__form" onSubmit={(e)=>handleSubmit(e)}>
            <h3>Login Form</h3>
            <hr />
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="exampleInputName1" className="form-label">
                Name
              </label>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                id="exampleInputName1"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                value={name}
                onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              />
             
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">
                Email address
              </label>
              <input
                type="email"
                className="form-control"
                id="exampleInputEmail1"
                aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                value={email}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
              <div id="emailHelp" className="form-text">
                we will never share your email with anyone else.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3">
              <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label">
                Password
              </label>
              <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                id="exampleInputPassword1"
                value={password}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="mb-3 form-check">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                className="form-check-input"
                id="exampleCheck1"
              />
              <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="exampleCheck1">
                Check me out
              </label>
            </div>
    
            <div className="d-grid gap-2">
               
                <button
                  className="btn btn-outline-danger"
                  type="submit"
                  onClick={register}
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
              
            </div>
          </form>
        </>
      );
    }
```

logout components code

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function Logout() {
  const products = useSelector((state) => state.products);
  const users = useSelector((state) => state.users);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    <>
      Welcome<span className="user_name">User</span>
      {products.map((products) => (
        <div key={products.id}>
          {products.name}-{products.price}
        </div>
      ))}
      {users.map((users) => (
        <div key={users.id}>
          {users.email}-{users.password}
        </div>
      ))}
      <button
        className="btn btn-outline-danger"
        type="submit"
        onClick={() => {
          dispatch({
            type: "LOGOUT",
          });
        }}
      >
        Logout
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

store which reducer components code

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
const initialState={
    users: [{
        email:"user1@fireflink.com",
        password:"123"
    }],
    loggedInUser:null,
    products:[{
        id:1,
        name:'pen',
        price:10
    },{
        id:2,
        name:'pencil',
        price:5
    },{
        id:3,
        name:'Eraser',
        price:15
    }],
    cart:[]
}

const reducer = (state=initialState,action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "REGISTER":
            return{
                ...state,
                users:action.payload
            }
        case "LOGOUT":
        return{
            ...state,
            users:null
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default createStore(reducer)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
My friend your App.jsx has error
you have used 
const **users** = useSelector((state) => state.users); 
and **users** is getting  array from store

 users= [{
        email:"user1@fireflink.com",
        password:"123"
    }] 


Try using Index
if (users[0].email && users[0].password)


if everything else with you code is fine the it should work.
```